# Не могу вывести из базы данных в OSCLASS id города

Tags: php, mysql

Только начал изучать OSCLASS и PHP. Пробовал всяко, не получается вывести из базы данных в OSCLASS id города. Вот мои попытки.

```
$conn = DBConnectionClass::newInstance();
$c_db = $conn->getOsclassDb();
$comm = new DBCommandClass($c_db);

//$idregion = $comm->prepare("SELECT pk_i_id FROM oc_t_region WHERE $_POST['sRegion']");

//$idcity = $comm->prepare("SELECT pk_i_id FROM oc_t_city WHERE Абакан");

//$idcity = $comm->query("SELECT pk_i_id FROM oc_t_city WHERE s_name = Абакан");

echo $idcity;

exit;
```

Очень, очень надо. Нигде в документации OSCLASS этой функции вывода id города не нашел. Таблица городов в OSCLASS такая:

```
--
-- Структура таблицы `oc_t_city`
--

CREATE TABLE `oc_t_city` (
  `pk_i_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fk_i_region_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `s_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `s_slug` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fk_c_country_code` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
$idcity = $comm->query("SELECT pk_i_id FROM oc_t_city WHERE s_name = 'Абакан'");
```

Comment: Попробовал. В базу данных записывается ноль.